# Creating custom validator in nest js

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, nestjs, class-validator

This is the shape of data:

```
{
  "saturday": [
    {
      "start": "10:00 AM",
      "end": "12:00 AM"
    }
  ],
  "sunday": [],
  ...
}
```

this is my **time-slot.interface**:

```
export enum DaysEnum {
  SATURDAY = 'saturday',
  SUNDAY = 'sunday',
  MONDAY = 'monday',
  TUESDAY = 'tuesday',
  WEDNESDAY = 'wednesday',
  THURSDAY = 'thursday',
  FRIDAY = 'friday',
}

export interface TimeSlot {
  start: Date;
  end: Date;
}

export type TimeSlots = Record<DaysEnum, TimeSlot[]>;
```

and this is my **time-slot.dot**:

```
import { IsNotEmpty, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { TimeSlots } from '../interfaces/time-slots.interface';

export class DoctorTimeSlotsDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  timeSlots: TimeSlots;
}
```

how can i make this custom validation?
timeSlots is a nested object of objects & arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsDate()
  @Type(() => Date)
  start: Date;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsDate()
  @Type(() => Date)
  @IsDateGreaterThan('start', { message: 'end must be greater than start' })
  end: Date;
}

export class DoctorTimeSlotsDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => TimeSlot)
  [DaysEnum.SATURDAY]: TimeSlot[];

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => TimeSlot)
  [DaysEnum.SUNDAY]: TimeSlot[];

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => TimeSlot)
  [DaysEnum.MONDAY]: TimeSlot[];

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => TimeSlot)
  [DaysEnum.TUESDAY]: TimeSlot[];

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => TimeSlot)
  [DaysEnum.WEDNESDAY]: TimeSlot[];

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => TimeSlot)
  [DaysEnum.THURSDAY]: TimeSlot[];

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => TimeSlot)
  [DaysEnum.FRIDAY]: TimeSlot[];
}
```